# I couldn't modify a folder in the computers section?

Tags: permissions, root

The name of the file

```
/usr/share/themes
```

I can copy, but couldn't cut or paste. Please provide instruction how I can change the permissions of this folder.

Comment: That is a `system` folder which has many - if not all - themes installed in Ubuntu! it is not wise to CUT and paste it somewhere else, as in doing so might possibly break your system!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it with your file manager used with super user privileges. Try

```
gksu nautilus
```

on terminal and try using the nautilus instance provided. But this is not recommended if you don't know really what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

- Open any terminal (ie press ctrl-alt-t)
- Enter the following command: `sudo nautilus`
- Enter your password
- What looks like an ordinary file manager will appear, but it will have root permissions everywhere.  Be very careful.  You can do some real damage with that much power.

Please be sure to exit that file manager when you are done.

Comment: He who issued -1 obviously didn't TRY the procedure.  Let me guess, my answers don't count unless it is performed entirely in TERMINAL COMMANDS?  If that's your policy, then you had best post that publicly where we can all see it.  My answers work, dammit, and that should be good enough for anyone!  I'm actually rather busy these days and it is nonsense like this that makes me wonder if I'm just wasting my time trying to help anyone here.  Mark my words, eventually I'm going to get so fed up that instead of helping, I'll just blog about how stupidly the downvotes are assigned here.

Comment: I have done some research on the forum and mother google and got these -
In terminal-
sudo su
[password]; then 
nautilus

Comment: @YashwanthRemidi, I told you WHAT I DO.  This what I do.  I don't particularly care if there's another way to do it.  You asked a question.  I posted a working answer which I have been doing for myself for some time now and some imbecile downvoted it for no apparent reason.  I don't understand your comment.  Are you taking credit for downvoting my sincere contribution?